# Find the last element from a List using ForEach loop

Tags: java, foreach

I am trying to find the most recent order associated with User and I have to use a forEach loop to iterate in reverse in order to find the most recent order.

Here is my code:

```
public Optional<Order> lastOrderFrom(User user, List<Order> orderList) {
        Optional<Order> result = 
                orderList
                .stream()
                .filter(order -> order.getUser().equals(user))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(result::new))
                .forEach(i -> System.out.println(user));

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can sort the list by some field and then get the last or first element. Read this links: https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/sort-list-of-objects-by-field-java https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-and-last-element-of-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: There is no need to sort a list to get the "last" element: you can simply scan then list looking for the maximum element according to some comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListIterator` to iterate in reverse:

```
for (ListIterator<Order> iter = orderList.listIterator(orderList.size());
        iter.hasPrevious(); ) {
    Order order = iter.previous();
    if (order.getUser().equals(user)) {
        return Optional.of(order);
    }
}
return Optional.empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to make a sorted list of orders for your desired customer.

In Java 21+, you can use the more general `SequencedCollection` in place of `List` as the type of the reference variable.

```java
SequencedCollection < Order > ordersForCustomer =
        orders
                .stream ( )
                .filter (
                        ( Order order ) -> order.customer.equalsIgnoreCase ( customer )
                )
                .sorted (
                        Comparator.comparing ( Order :: whenPlaced )
                )
                .toList ( );
```

In Java 21+, then use `SequencedCollection#getLast` on the `List` to obtain the most recent order for that customer.

```
ordersForCustomer.getLast ( )
```

Here is full example code.

```java
package work.basil.example.streaming;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;

public class MostRecentOrderForCustomer
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        MostRecentOrderForCustomer app = new MostRecentOrderForCustomer ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        Collection < Order > orders =
                List.of (
                        new Order ( 1 , "Alice" , Instant.now ( ).minus ( Duration.ofHours ( 12 ) ) ) ,
                        new Order ( 2 , "Bob" , Instant.now ( ).minus ( Duration.ofHours ( 9 ) ) ) ,
                        new Order ( 3 , "Bob" , Instant.now ( ).minus ( Duration.ofHours ( 5 ) ) ) ,
                        new Order ( 4 , "Alice" , Instant.now ( ).minus ( Duration.ofHours ( 2 ) ) )
                );
        orders.forEach ( System.out :: println );
        Optional < Order > mostRecentOrderForBob = this.lastOrderFrom ( "Bob" , orders );
        System.out.println ( "mostRecentOrderForBob = " + mostRecentOrderForBob );
    }

    Optional < Order > lastOrderFrom ( final String customer , final Collection < Order > orders )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull ( customer );
        Objects.requireNonNull ( orders );
        if ( orders.isEmpty ( ) ) return Optional.empty ( );
        SequencedCollection < Order > ordersForCustomer =
                orders
                        .stream ( )
                        .filter (
                                ( Order order ) -> order.customer.equalsIgnoreCase ( customer )
                        )
                        .sorted (
                                Comparator.comparing ( Order :: whenPlaced )
                        )
                        .toList ( );
        if ( ordersForCustomer.isEmpty ( ) ) return Optional.empty ( );
        return Optional.of ( ordersForCustomer.getLast ( ) );
    }

    record Order( int id , String customer , Instant whenPlaced ) { }
}
```

When run:

```
Order[id=1, customer=Alice, whenPlaced=2023-11-28T14:12:42.894954Z]
Order[id=2, customer=Bob, whenPlaced=2023-11-28T17:12:42.895321Z]
Order[id=3, customer=Bob, whenPlaced=2023-11-28T21:12:42.895323Z]
Order[id=4, customer=Alice, whenPlaced=2023-11-29T00:12:42.895324Z]
mostRecentOrderForBob = Optional[Order[id=3, customer=Bob, whenPlaced=2023-11-28T21:12:42.895323Z]]
```